# Cancel button in date picker

Tags: datepicker, sencha-touch-2

I have created a datepicker field. When the date picker is displayed and the cancel button is tapped, it takes the first value as the default value. I need to check a condition where I can handle the cancel button on the date pipcker field

```
 case 'Date':
        console.log('date value: '+value);
        var dt = new Date(value);
        console.log('new date: '+dt);
        if (dt == 'Invalid Date' || dt == 'NaN/NaN/0NaN') {
            value = '';
        } else {
            value = dt;
        }
        element = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            layout : 'hbox',
            items : [ {
                xtype : 'datepickerfield',
                label : label,
                name : 'standTimeEdit',
                defaultDateFormat : 'D M Y',
                value : value,
                width : '100%',
                style : 'border: 0px solid gray;border-radius:10px',
                listeners:{
                    change:function(){
                         value = dt;
                    }
                    cancel:function(){
                        console.log('cancel event fired');
                    }
                }
            } ]
        });
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [cancel event](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-event-cancel) of date picker field which will `fired when the cancel button is tapped and the values are reverted back to what they were`.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I have updated the code. The cancel event is not getting fired.

Comment: The issue could be that Cancel event is there for "Date" but not for "DatePicker".

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by overriding the cancel event in the picker.

```
var picker = this.getPicker();
picker.on('cancel',function(){
                            if(defValue == ''){
                                if(count > 1){
                                    picker.setValue(preVal);
                                    dateObj.setValue({day: preVal.getDate(), month: (preVal.getMonth()+1), year : preVal.getFullYear()});
                                }
                                else{
                                    picker.setValue(null);
                                    dateObj.setValue(null);
                                    count--;
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

This gave me a handle to the cancel button in the picker.